# The disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption

Unfortunately I experienced a power failure during an update from Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS to 12.04 LTS (it was a power failure of more then 40 minutes so batteries charge of the UPS weren't enough).

When I restarted the server and Ubuntu is starting I have to input the passphrase to unlock the encrypted partitions of the disks (all are encrypted) but also if the `/` is correctly decrypted appears the message:

```
the disk drive for / is not ready yet or not present
press S to skip or M to mount it manually.
```

With option `S` results are that every partition based on `/` is not mounted. With option `M` a reduced shell is active and I am able to mount the partition manually because after the mount a `ls -la` command shows my directories (also if `/home` contents doesn't look very good) but in the reduced shell I a not able to do much more then mount and `ls`.

1. How can I correct definitively the situation?
2. About the disk encryption: probably it wasn't a good choice in practice I need encryption security only for the data meaning user directories and data directories shared using samba.

I would appreciate every comment, suggestion and criticism about disk encryption because it is very useful but prevents the possibility to remotely turn off and on the server that actually is a new constraint for me so I can happily accept a solution permitting to start up the server and then after it will go up enable and mount the encrypted partitions (hopefully it would work also from a remote console).